# python: How to delete all items in a group if one matches a condition (string comparison)?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

Disclaimer: I tried to do this in SQL and none of the answers/my attempts worked so I have been trying to use python as it seems to be better suited

I am hoping to create a function that can delete all items in a group if any one of them matches a specific condition.

Specifically, I have a dataset 'family' and I want to delete all members of the family if that family contains twins.

A portion of the dataset looks like this:

| Subject ID | Mother_ID | Zygosity_SR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2001 | MZ |
| 1002 | 2001 | MZ |
| 1003 | 2001 | NotTwin |
| 1004 | 2002 | NotTwin |
| 1005 | 2002 | NotTwin |

In this case I want to delete all rows with individuals with the same Mother_ID as the Subjects with Zygosity_SR = MZ.

My resulting table would look like this:

| Subject ID | Mother_ID | Zygosity_SR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | 2002 | NotTwin |
| 1005 | 2002 | NotTwin |

This is the python code I have:

```
import pandas as pd

family = pd.read_excel('HCP database 97 excel vers.xlsx')
family_drop = family.groupby('Mother_ID').filter(lambda x: x['ZygositySR'].str.strip() == 'MZ' )
family_drop.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
family_drop = family_drop[['Subject','Mother_ID']] 
print(family_drop)
```

I have been getting the error:

```
TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool
```

Any tips at all on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: how do we identify twins? If there are duplicates in `Zygosity_SR`, we consider it to be a twin? There is nothing in the original data that says `MZ` rows are twins. To generalize the solution, please share additional information. Otherwise, it will be customized solution for value `MZ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`DataFrameGroupBy.filter()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) wants a single boolean to determine if a given group should be returned.

In this case, it looks like you're trying to get groups where "all `Zygosity_SR` values are not `MZ`":

```py
family.groupby('Mother_ID').filter(
    lambda group: all(group.Zygosity_SR.str.strip() != 'MZ'))

#    Subject ID  Mother_ID Zygosity_SR
# 3        1004       2002     NotTwin
# 4        1005       2002     NotTwin
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to remove the MZ and their mothers' rows:

```
tdf = df[df['Zygosity_SR'] == 'MZ']   # rows of MZ
tset = set(tdf['Mother_ID'])          # set of MZ's Mother_ID
fdf = df[~df['Mother_ID'].isin(tset)] # rows with NotTwin Mother_ID
```

This condition `~df['Mother_ID'].isin(tset)` means filter out Mother_ID in the set.

```
print(fdf)
   Subject ID  Mother_ID Zygosity_SR
3        1004       2002     NotTwin
4        1005       2002     NotTwin
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this SQL statement will do what you're asking (delete all subjects whose mother has had twins).

```
delete 
from table 
where mother_id in (
    select distinct mother_id 
    from table 
    where Zygosity_SR = MZ
)
```